# Grub rescue error/issue after a partition was removed from a dual boot system

Tags: grub

My computer previously used a dual boot system with Windows Vista and Kali both installed. Eventually, after rarely using Kali, I removed that partition, but now I can't start Windows due to a grub rescue issue.

I've followed some videos explaining how to check the partition Kali was on, but I assume that is not solving the issue because the partition was removed!?! I can list (ls) the partitions which are there, but it falls down at the insmod normal command. I'm getting an error at that point "Error unknown filesystem"

I've made a bootable Windows Vista DVD, which works, but only if the original hard drive is not connected (I can also start Kali from a live bootable DVD if the hard drive is not connected). If the hard drive is connected the DVD drive won't kick-in, even though I've tried setting it up in the BIOS as the only option to use in the boot sequence. If I can get either of those systems working with the hard drive still connected, I think I should be able to retrieve the data that I'm looking for.

If anyone can see something that I'm missing, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Grub is divided into multiple stages. A part of it was (probably) installed on your Kali partition. A solution would be to install grub again.